# How to set same view for all directories to minature in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

Every single directory viewed by explorer looks different. Once it displays minatures other time details etc.

I would like to set view for minatures everywhere. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In Explorer format a directory  layout as you want it, then click on **Tools** -> **Folder Options...** and select the **View** tab.

Under **Advanced settings:** clear **Remember each folder's view settings** and press the **Apply** button, then under **Folder views** click on **Apply to All Folders** and press **OK**.

That's it!